# How do I move an element in a straight line with a start button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, let's say I have a box created in HTML/CSS.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    #box {
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
      left: 280px;
      top: 180px;
    }
  </style>
```

Style does not matter all that much.

How do I get that box to start on the left side of the page and press a start button that brings it to about the middle of the page WITHOUT having to press a stop button using JavaScript?

I know how to move it with arrow keys, a continuous movement, or a start and then stop button, but not how to just change the position.

Comment: Can you show how you would implement it with a stop button? It’s probably easiest to explain how to remove that.

Comment: You could add a new CSS class that positions the element in the centre with Javascript and/or JQuery.

Comment: Do you want this to be animated or just pop into position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: $(window).width() - $("#box").width()
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 280px;
  top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<button>Go</button>
```

You can also do this with style without animation.

```
#box.moved {
  left: calc(100% - 48px);
}
```